# Calculate quantity of ions eliminated by acids

Tags: physical-chemistry, ph

I have limescale $(\ce{CaCO3})$ and a solution of hydrochloric acid at 30% concentration of hydrogen chloride $(\ce{HCl}).$

This acid-base equation

$$\ce{HCl + H2O -> H3O^+ + Cl^-}$$

with the following data:

$m_\mathrm{solution} = \pu{1180 g},$ $m_\ce{HCl} = \pu{354 g},$ $M_\ce{HCl} = \pu{36.5 g mol-1},$ $n_\ce{HCl} = \pu{9.70 mol}.$

But now I need to calculate how much of $ \ce{CO3^{2-}} $ is eliminated by the $\ce{H3O^+}.$ I've written the molar concentration of $\ce{H3O^+}$ which is $\pu{9.70 mol L-1}$ and I calculated the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the solution:

$$\mathrm{pH} = -\log_{10}9.70 = 0.986$$

But I have no idea how to go from there.

Comment: The term *chloridric acid* is highly unusual, called usually hydrochloric acid. // Search for the CaCO3 vs HCl equivalence on the molar amount level.

Comment: You should guess that  $\ce{1 mol CO3^{2-}}$ reacts with  $\ce{2 mol H3O+}$ to produce $\ce{CO2 + H2O}$. So how many moles $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ are reacting with $\ce{9.7 mol }$ acid ?